# Struggling to use main() in python

Tags: python, function, call, program-entry-point

I am struggling to understand how to use main() in python. I want to call another function into main, but only run the function if a while loop is true. Here is my code in main():

```
from Formula import main_calculation as mc

def main():
    escape = input("\nPress the letter 'E' to quit the calculation," +
                   "\notherwise, press any letter to continue: ")
    while escape != 'e':
        run_calc = mc
        return run_calc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am quite lost in how I should be using main. Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: I guess bottom line is mistaken. Change the condition as `__name__ == '__main__' `

Answer (score 0):

The main() function and the if-condition at the bottom of your code are only there to prevent executing the code if your file is imported. For simplicity just remove them.

Inside of main() you can write code like anywhere else. So your example should be:

```
while escape != 'e':
    mc() # call the function
```

You don't have to return anything, main is just there to prevent auto-execution of your code when importing.

Comment: Thank you. But if I do what you suggest, I get the following error 'mc' is not callable

Comment: @AllanVandyke Is mc a function?

Comment: Good point. No, it is a file with multiple functions?

Answer (score 0):

I have spent hours trying to get this right. Finally, this works:

```
from importlib import reload


# place imported module in a function, to make it only run when called
def mc_import():
from Formula import main_calculation as mc
return mc

calc = mc_import()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   escape = ''
   while escape != 'e':
       escape = input("\nPress the letter 'E' to quit the calculation," +
                      "\notherwise, press any letter to continue: ")
       if escape != 'e':
          reload(calc)
```

---

```
from importlib import reload

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from Formula import main_calculation as mc
    escape = ''
    while escape != 'e':
        escape = input("\nPress the letter 'E' to quit the calculation," +
                       "\notherwise, press any letter to continue: ")
        if escape != 'e':
            reload(mc)
```

Comment: While this might work, it seems very convoluted. You place the import in a function, just to call it immediately. You said you wanted to run a function in a loop, but now you're reloading a module (which might as a side effect run a function). Does your code change between calling the function? If not, then there is very surely a more idiomatic way to do what you try to do. If you update your function with the layout and code of `Formula` maybe we could find a better way to archive what you want.

Comment: Thank you. What you are saying makes sense. My initial description was wrong. I am actually calling an entire module, having multiple functions. I will make some changes, and post what I change. I will also post a description of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I have modified my code as shown above. It does work how I want it to work. Still not sure if it is the best result?